# change applicationIconBadgeNumber color

Tags: ios, iphone, badge

Taking a long shot here.
Is there an option to change `applicationIconBadgeNumber` color from red to something else? (in IOS 7)

Our logo is red and the badge doesn't stand out enough...

Comment: I've never seen this done before. I'd say no unless you jailbreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot change the color or size of the pending notification badge.

According to Apple guidelines [iOS Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html)

> A badge is a small red oval that displays the number of pending notification items (a badge appears over the upper-right corner of an app’s icon). You have no control over the size or color of the badge.

try some samples

https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible:

> A badge is a small red oval that displays the number of pending notification items (a badge appears over the upper-right corner of an app’s icon). You have no control over the size or color of the badge.

More information: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without jailbreak!